# ASP.NET Core 3.1 application having InProcess hosting model is getting timeout after 1 minute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What should be done if we want to increase the request timeout for asp.net core 3.1 application with InProcess hosting model? Our application is getting timed out in such scenarios.

We tried setting requestTimeout property in web.config but as written in link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#in-process-hosting-model), it is getting ignored.

So we are not sure what can be done for the same, please help.

Thanks
Hardik

Comment: refer this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23160), suggest writing custom middleware for request timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Add `web.config` file to your project and write like these codes on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can read more on [here](https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/increase-the-timeout-of-asp-net-core-application-9a7b4f6deebf)

Comment: But as per the link mentioned in my question, requestTimeout property is not getting used for InProcess hosting model, and hence the solution you provided is not working.